# Jersey JAX-RS 3 level nested object has null value

Tags: jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have the below JSON code that needs to be parsed. I'm using the corresponding JAX-RS models. The problem is that the `paymillClient` object is null. If I add `currency` as a string inside the `PaymillSubscription` object, it returns `EUR` value, not null. So there appears to be a problem with the `PaymillClient` object, not plain strings. Could there be a limit to the number of nested objects for parsing ? Ex, max 2 nested objects. So because there are 3 in my case, it doesn't work.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the JSON code that needs to be parsed at all. I just need to make it work with the JAX-RS implementation.

```
{  
   "event":{  
      "event_type":"subscription.succeeded",
      "event_resource":{  
         "subscription":{  
            "id":"sub_29f144a3bc32c71f96e2",
            "offer":{  },
            "livemode":false,
            "amount":200,
            "temp_amount":null,
            "currency":"EUR",
            "name":"Monthly subscription",
            "interval":"1 MONTH",
            "trial_start":null,
            "trial_end":null,
            "period_of_validity":null,
            "end_of_period":null,
            "next_capture_at":1428939744,
            "created_at":1426264944,
            "updated_at":1426264944,
            "canceled_at":null,
            "payment":{  },
            "app_id":null,
            "is_canceled":false,
            "is_deleted":false,
            "status":"active",
            "client":{ 
              "id":"client_c0c24aa7f97e1b8ed15d" 
            }
         },
         "transaction":{  }
      },
      "created_at":1426264944,
      "app_id":null
   }
}
```

**PaymillEventContainer:**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymillEventContainer
{
    private PaymillEvent event;
}
```

**PaymillEvent:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymillEvent
{
    @XmlElement(name = "event_type") @DocumentationExample(value = "subscription.succeeded") private String eventType;
    @XmlElement(name = "event_resource") private PaymillEventResource eventResource;
}
```

**PaymillEventResource:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymillEventResource
{
    private PaymillClient client;
    private PaymillOffer offer;
    private PaymillSubscription subscription;
}
```

**PaymillSubscription:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymillSubscription
{
    private PaymillClient client;
    private PaymillOffer offer;
}
```

**PaymillClient:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PaymillClient
{
    @DocumentationExample(value = "client_c0c24aa7f97e1b8ed15d") private String id;
}
```

**API endpoint code:**

```
public Response postSubscriptionSucceeded(PaymillEventContainer paymillEventContainer)
    {
        PaymillEvent paymillEvent = paymillEventContainer.getPaymillEvent();
        PaymillEventResource paymillEventResource = paymillEvent.getEventResource();

        PaymillSubscription paymillSubscription = paymillEventResource.getSubscription();
        PaymillClient paymillClient = paymillSubscription.getPaymillClient();
        PaymillOffer paymillOffer = paymillSubscription.getPaymillOffer();

        String clientId = paymillClient.getId(); // NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: Could you give us listing of PaymillSubscription?

Comment: My bad, forgot the PaymillSubscription, it has PaymillClient as well. So that is not the issue. Edited and added PaymillSubscription as well. Both PaymillEventResource and PaymillSubscription contain the PaymillClient because there are 2 different API endpoints which return the client in either object (I know, not pretty, but it's not up to me). Either way, PaymillClient is null in both cases.

Comment: Shouldn't you call getClient() on paymillSubscription instead of getPaymillClient()?

Comment: Tried it now. Still null.

Comment: it seems I found an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I tried to run your code on your machine and also received null (note, that I'm using MOXy to unmarshall JSON). Then, I tried to experiment with it a little and found really funny things:
1. If you will remove all null-valued fields from your JSON, all works just perfect.
2. If you will add another field to PaymillSubscription. I added private Test test, where Test is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test {
    private String id;
}
```

And will send this "test" object between last null-valued field in subscription object and "client" field:

```
"test":{"id":"sadas"},
"client":{ 
    "id":"client_c0c24aa7f97e1b8ed15d"
 }
```

Then "test" would be null, but "client" will be parsed as expected.
3. If you will add all null-valued objects into model (I mean, create respective fields in PaymillSubscription class) all works just perfect.
It seems, that by default JAXB specification doesn't allow JSON with unrecognized fields, but MOXy still tries to parse it (and sometimes produces errors).

Comment: 1) You mean attrs like app_id and canceled_at ? If so, like I said, I cannot change the request JSON at all. 2) Add the test model inside the JSON? I guess same thing as 1, cannot change the JSON. 3) I presume this is doable, I'll try it now.

Comment: Yes. You could try what I wrote in 2) or 3).

Comment: Lol, it appears it works using your 3rd idea. Very nicely done finding the solution, but why the hell doesn't it work with null values that are not declared inside the model? Just a bug inside Jersey?

Comment: I lurked a little and it seems that no. For example, when I use Jackson instead of MOXy it directly blames me for unknown fields in JSON. It seems, that by default JAXB specification doesn't allow JSON with unrecognized fields (unfortunatelly I cannot find anything proving my words).